# Trouble to use net conection in Android Studio to get a link json

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I have the form below where I read a json from a web address

http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php

which gives me a **json**-type string

```
{
  "clientes":[
     {
       "idClientesT":"1",
       "tipo":"s",
       "nome":"Carlos"},
     {
       "idClientesT":"2",
       "tipo":"s",
       "nome":"Rogério"
     }
  ]
}
```

So I get her on `AndroidStudio` with `Activity` below:

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes.JsonClass;

public class form extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form);
    }

    public void listaClientes (View View) {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        String url = "http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php";
        JsonClass json = new JsonClass();
        JSONObject clientesLista = json.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        clientes(clientesLista);
    }

    public void clientes(JSONObject jsonCli) {

        try {

            JSONArray arrayPlanetas = jsonCli.getJSONArray("clientes");

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayPlanetas.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject cliente = arrayPlanetas.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("idClientesT", cliente.getString("idClientesT"));
                Log.d("tipo", cliente.getString("tipo"));
                Log.d("nome", cliente.getString("nome"));

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This **code** works normally.

However, it is necessary to place the code stretch below;

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Otherwise, the INTERNET connection is NOT established.

However, I've already added INTERNET access permission in AndroidManifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="carcleo.com.radiosingular">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".principal" />
        <activity android:name=".form" />
        <activity android:name=".retrofit" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But no use.

If I remove this block of code

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

The **connection** to the **INTERNET** does not happen.

The problem is that how many times I need to access **INTERNET** will be the same number of times that I will have to make use of this code snippet?

Is there no general configuration file for this in Android Studio?

jSon Class:

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes;

import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.ClientProtocolException;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPost;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class JsonClass {

    InputStream input = null;
    JSONObject jObect = null;
    String json = "";

    //Recebe sua url
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        //HTTP request
        try {
            // default HttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            input = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            input.close();

            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Transforma a String de resposta em um JSonObject
        try {
            jObect = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // retorna o objeto
        return jObect;

    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked the logcat for the errors with the reason why it does not work?

Comment: are you defined your function in on create() ??? your on create is empty

Comment: no, i put a buttom in the form (activity) and then call it from a onClick function listaClientes

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER be setting a thread strict mode policy like that.  Its completely the wrong solution.  Instead, you should NOT do networking on the main thread-  doing so even with strict mode turned off so you don't crash will cause your app to go completely unresponsive.

Comment: THis code should never be used.  Instead, you should be doing the network request (which happens in getJsonFromUrl) on another thread.

Comment: so : JSONObject clientesLista = json.getJSONFromUrl(url). You can see it in the ask. But notworks without the block

Comment: Righjt-  because it can't be run from the main thread, because it makes a network request.  Call it on another thread.m  In Android, no network requests are allowed on the main thread.  What your block does is turn off that rule, which is a bad idea.

Comment: but i'm not call from main thead. I'm calling it from onClick of button int the form. See it in the question!

Comment: @CarlosRocha can you show us the code for `getJSONFromUrl`.

Comment: String url = "http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php";
        JsonClass json = new JsonClass();
        JSONObject clientesLista = json.getJSONFromUrl(url);

Comment: its in the question!

Comment: @CarlosRocha onClick, and all UI functions, run on the main thread.  I don't think you understand what a Thread is.

Comment: ok. but i would like know, where i need put it block code to works. Cause i dont put it, then code not works. dou you understand-me?

Comment: @CarlosRocha I do.  ANd the answer is-  you don't put the strict mode anywhere.  You move the call to getJsonFromUrl to a new thread or AsyncTask.  Then it all works.  ANd you need to take a step back and stop worrying about "how to make it work" and start trying to understand how it works, because you will run into issues like this constantly.

Comment: jSon Class: add in the end of ask.